# Disabling warnings generated by java ant

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, ant

I'm using java ant in order to generate certificates and keystores for some entities, which I will use in a java app later. 
The application is for learning purposes only, I know it's a bad idea to store passwords in plain text.

The command that i'm using is :

```
<exec command="keytool -genkey -alias test -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024 
     -keystore keyst.ks -keypass pass -storepass pass -dname &quot;
     CN=Duke, OU=MyUnit, O=MyOrg, C=US&quot;"/>
```

Although the command works as expected, after each line i'm given a couple of warnings :

> ```
>   [exec] The command attribute is deprecated.
> ```

```
   [exec] Please use the executable attribute and nested arg elements.
```

I'm curious if there is any way that I can surpress these warnings, other than not using nested args. 
The script generates a lot of text output, and the warnings make it harder to track the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `command` attribute on the `exec` task has been deprecated and has been since Ant 1.5 when I first started using Ant. I suspect that it will remain *deprecated* for quite a long time. There's no issue besides the warning, but you might as well use the `execute` attribute which replaces it.

The only issue is that the `execute` attribute (unlike the `command` attribute) assumes that command names can contain whitespace, so you can't simply cram the entire command into the `execute` attribute. Instead, you must use the `<arg>` subtesk to pass in the parameters for the command:

```
<exec executable="keytool">
    <arg line="-genkey -alias test -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024 -keystore keyst.ks -keypass pass -storepass pass -dname &quot;CN=Duke, OU=MyUnit, O=MyOrg, C=US&quot;"
</exec>
```

That last parameter, `-dname` might present a problem. However, you can use the `<arg value=">` subtask to get around this problem:

```
<exec executable="keytool">
    <arg value="-genkey"/>
    <arg value="-alias"/>
    <arg value="test"/>
    <arg value="-keyalg"/>
    <arg value="DSA"/>
    <arg value="-keysize"/>
    <arg value="1024"/>
    <arg value="-keystore"/>
    <arg value="keyst.ks"/>
    <arg value="-keypass"/>
    <arg value="pass"/>
    <arg value="-storepass"/>
    <arg value="pass"/>
    <arg value="-dname"/>
    <arg value="CN=Duke, OU=MyUnit, O=MyOrg, C=US"/>
</exec>
```

Note that the parameter for the `-dname` field no longer needs `&quot;` around it. The `<arg value>` understands this is a single value despite whitespace.

You can combine the `line` and `value` types of the `<arg>` subtask too:

```
    <exec executable="keytool">
        <arg line="-genkey -alias test -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024"/>
        <arg line="-keystore keyst.ks -keypass pass123 -storepass pass123 -dname"/>
        <arg value="CN=Duke, OU=MyUnit, O=MyOrg, C=US"/>
    </exec>
```

At least, I've done that without any issues before.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, read the warning.  Don't use the `command` attribute; use `executable` and nested arg elements.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

So it'd look like this:

```
<exec executable="keytool">
 <arg value="-genkey"/>
 <!-- I'll leave the rest for you; read the docs -->
</exec>
```